# During calculation of "distance average" in knn imputation method for replacing NaN value in particular column

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I encounter this problem when I implement the Knn imputation method for handling missing data from scratch. I create a dummy dataset and find the nearest neighbors for rows that contain missing values here is my dataset

```
    A    B    C       D       E
0   NaN  2.0   4.0    10.0    100.0
1   NaN  3.0   9.0    12.0     NaN
2   5.0  2.0   20.0   50.0    75.0
3   3.0  5.0   7.0     NaN    150.0
4   2.0  9.0   7.0    30.0    90.0
```

for **row 0** the nearest neighbors are **1 and 2** and to replace the **NaN** value at (0, A) we compute the distance average between the nearest neighbors value in the same column but what if one of the nearest neighbors value is also **NaN**?

**Example**:

let suppose the nearest neighbors for **row 3** is **2 and 4** so in row 3 the missing value in column **D** and to replace this missing value we compute distance average between nearest neighbors value in column D which is like that

> distance average = [(1/D1) * 50.0 + (1/D2) * 30.0]/2

and replace the nan value at (3, D) with this average (where D1 and D2 are corresponding **nan euclidian distance**). But in the case of **row 0**  the nearest neighbor is **1 and 2** and to replace the nan value at (0, A ) we need to compute the distance average between row 1 and 2 value in column A the value at **(2, A) is 5.0** great but at **(1, A) it's NaN** so we can't compute like that

> distance average = [(1/D3) * NaN + (1/D4) * 5.0]/2

so how do we replace the NaN value at (0, A)? and how does sklearn KNNImputer handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sklearn [`KNNImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) uses the [`nan_euclidean_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.nan_euclidean_distances.html) metric as a default. According to its [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#knnimpute)

> If a sample has more than one feature missing, then the neighbors for
> that sample can be different depending on the particular feature being
> imputed.

The algorithm might use different sets of neighborhoods to impute the single missing value in column D and the two missing values in column A.

This is a simple implementation of the KNNImputer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer


A = [np.nan, np.nan, 5, 3, 2]
B = [2, 3, 2, 5, 9]
C = [4, 9, 20, 7, 7]
D = [10, 12, 50, np.nan, 30]
E = [100, np.nan, 75, 150, 90]

columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A, B, C, D, E)),
                    columns=columns)

imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)

imputed_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(data), columns=columns)
```

This is the output:

```
     A    B     C     D      E
0  3.5  2.0   4.0  10.0  100.0
1  2.5  3.0   9.0  12.0  125.0
2  5.0  2.0  20.0  50.0   75.0
3  3.0  5.0   7.0  11.0  150.0
4  2.0  9.0   7.0  30.0   90.0
```